# Linq query biz object to discover unique records..would this be a case for recursion

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

Not really sure how to go about this and was hoping the brainiacs here could point me in the right direction. I have a biz object that is a collection and of course each item in the top level collection has some properties but one of the properties is a collection of some related child records....and it is these child records that have the values I am looking for.

So that was the high level overview not moving closer...

The parent object is a collection of events (in essence school classes) and the related child collection is the instructors...such a primary, secondary, aide, observer..etc.

Now the idea is to create an instructor calendar that shows what events Bob..etc has for the month.

So the instructors would be on the left (Y axis) of the calendar while the days of the month would be across the top (X Axis)....however as I mentioned the instructors have to be mined out of the biz obj.

Now I am at a stage in development that I can rework this biz object if there is a better way that I should implement.

---

Now in my limited knowledge base the best I could come up with was to write a foreach loop to extract the instructors querying one at a time...adding the results to another collection and then taking the new collection and removing dupes or dupe check and don't insert during loop.

Something like List.ForEach(x => x.TeamMember....???)

The parent object:

```
public class CalendarEvent
{
    #region Internal Fields

        private readonly string _id;
        private DateTime _start;
        private DateTime _end;
        private string _eventname;

        private TeamMembers _eventteam;

    #endregion

    #region Const

        public CalendarEvent(string id, DateTime start, DateTime end, string evtname)
        {
            this._id = id;
            this._start = start;
            this._end = end;
            this._eventname = evtname;
        }

    #endregion

    #region Props

        public string ID { get { return _id; } }
        public DateTime Start { get { return _start; } }
        public DateTime End { get { return _end; } }
        public string EventName { get { return _eventname; } }

        public TeamMembers EventTeamMembers { get; set; }



    #endregion

}
```

The child object TeamMembers:

```
public class TeamMember
{
    #region Internal Fields

        private readonly string _firstname;
        private readonly string _fullname;
        private readonly string _userid;

        private TeamRoles.TeamMemberRole _memberrole;

        //private string _resid;

    #endregion

    #region Const

        public TeamMember(string fullname, string firstname, string userid)
        {
            this._fullname = fullname;
            this._firstname = firstname;
            this._userid = userid;
            //this._resid = resid;
        }

    #endregion

    #region Props

        public string FirstName { get { return _firstname; } }
        public string FullName { get { return _fullname; } }
        public string UserId { get { return _userid; } }
        //public string SpeakerID { get { return _resid; } }

        public TeamRoles.TeamMemberRole TeamMemberRole { get; set; }

    #endregion

}
```

So the object would look like this:

```
CalendarEvent.Count = 25

CalendarEvent[0]
   EventId = GUID
   Start = May 1st
   End = May 12th
   EventName = Pencil Sharpening
   TeamMembers(.count = 3)
```

So I need to extract all three team members but..if I have already added them to the Y axis collection (ie the collection that will be bound to the Y axis) then skip or remove later with List.Distinct() or similiar.

Any ideas, suggestions or best practices would be very much appreciated.

---

My apologies but I am struggling with one aspect of what has been shown to me. I'm sure @ Ben Aaronson has already answered this but it is going over my head.

I understand the comment that Event know about TeamMembers but not the reverse. I also understand this statement:

"You need to store all the events somewhere. You can't start from just the team members and get events without also having access to the events at the same time..."

agreed but I do have such a collection to begin with in the proposed solution below called _allevents...so I was hoping to just pull out a distinct collection of TeamMembers.

For example I wrote this but my lack of knowledge means this is just a trip around the mulberry bush....I get what I already had???

```
List<CalendarEvent> asdf = _allevents.Where(evt => evt.TeamMembers.Any(tm => tm.UserId != string.Empty)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: By the way, are you aware of the syntax `get; private set;` for properties? Can cut out a lot of unnecessary code in your example

Comment: I answered but now that I reread the question I'm not sure it fully addresses your requirements. What precisely is it you need?

Comment: Well based upon your solution I might be able to get there. I don't want to project allevents...rather "allTeamMembers"....also my IEnumerable would be IEnumerable<TeamMember> and I would word smith the name....now that being said it's not your job to do my homework and from what I can tell you have given me a very helpful boost in the right direction.

Comment: You don't define the `TeamMembers` type.

Comment: "I don't want to project allevents...rather "allTeamMembers"" You *need* to store all the events somewhere. You can't start from just the team members and get events without also having access to the events at the same time.

Comment: Basically because `CalendarEvent` has a reference to all relevant `TeamMember`, but `TeamMember` doesn't have a reference to any `CalendarEvent`, you can start with just a collection of `CalendarEvent`s and get whatever you want- including a collection of all distinct `TeamMembers` across all events. But you can't do the same the other way around.

Comment: See edit..I'm sorry for my lack of understanding.

Comment: @user1278561 I've updated the answer for the last part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would look something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<CalendarEvent> EventsForTeamMember(string userId)
{
    return _allEvents.Where(e => e.EventTeamMembers.Any(tm => tm.UserId == userId));
}
```

In this example, it's assumed you have a collection with all your possible events in scope called `_allEvents`. I'm also assuming that `TeamMembers` is some sort of collection of `TeamMember`s that you can perform LINQ queries on. And if you want to look up team members by something other than user ID, the change should hopefully be relatively straightforward to see.

**EDIT**

To pull out a distinct list of team members, as in the updated part of your question, you're close, but you need to remember that you want to *select* the team member out of the event. So this would look like:

```
public IEnumerable<TeamMember> AllTeamMembersForEvents()
{
    return _allEvents.SelectMany(e => e.EventTeamMembers).Distinct();
}
```

The key bit here is the `SelectMany`, which flattens collections.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience. That is the bit of information I was not connecting on.

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the object collecting a new anonymous object with team member and date using `SelectMany` will "flatten" and concatenate these elements-- then sort them by team member and then by date.  Once you have the list ordered by team member and date you can just iterate over it to build you calendar as the items will be in the needed order.

Like this:

```
var byMemberDate = events
                    .SelectMany(e => e.EventTeamMembers
                                      .Select(m => new { evnt = e, member = m}))
                    .OrderBy(item => item.member.FullName)
                    .ThenBy(item => item.evnt.Start);

foreach(var item in byMemberDate)
  Console.WriteLine("Member = "+item.member.FullName+" Date = "+item.evnt.Start);
```

output:

```
Member = gi joe Date = 1/1/2014 1:01:01 AM
Member = hogan long Date = 1/1/2014 1:01:01 AM
Member = sam spade Date = 1/1/2014 1:01:01 AM
Member = sam spade Date = 2/2/2014 2:02:02 AM
Member = three three Date = 3/3/2014 3:03:03 AM
```

Full working code here 
https://gist.github.com/hoganlong/1bad5892febf3f48b55f

---

A side note occurred to me.  If you want a list of team members each with a list of dates that is easy too.  Just use `GroupBy` after your `SelectMany`

Like this:

```
var byMembers = events
                .SelectMany(e => e.EventTeamMembers
                                  .Select(m => new { start = e.Start, name = m.FullName}))
                .GroupBy(item => item.name)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
```